# Using catalase-test to determine if Staphylo- or Streptococcus

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, methods

If the microscope clearly shows bacteria of cocci morphology but it is difficult to determine if they are Staphylo- or Streptococcus, are catalase tests a good way to differentiate between the two since Staphylococcus are positive and Streptococcus are negative? Are there any traps/exceptions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally yes: streptococci are catalase negative while staphylococci are catalase positive.

> [The catalase test is important in distinguishing streptococci (catalase-negative) [from] staphylococci which are catalase positive.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK8448/)

> [Unlike *Staphylococcus*, all streptococci lack the enzyme catalase.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK7611/)

However, there are exceptions to every rule:

[Catalase negative *Staphylococcus aureus*.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3279781)

[Catalase positive *Streptococcus sp.*](http://ijs.microbiologyresearch.org/content/journal/ijsem/10.1099/00207713-50-2-759)